# where does UIPageViewController cache the previous and next controllers?

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

When UIPageViewController calls the datasource with the viewControllerBeforeViewController and viewControllerAfterViewController methods, it is obtaining the view controller that will be displayed when the user swipes again. Is there a writable property in which it keeps this data until it needs to use it? The reason I ask is that I want the user to be able to swipe to go forward or backward, or simply tap to advance to the next slide. However, if I tap to advance from the first slide to the second (advancing using the setViewControllers method), I cannot swipe backwards; there is no back controller to go back to. This affects only the second slide. So I need to be able to set the previous controller programmatically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I had the similar issue and discovered, that `UIPageViewController` store its cached View Controller pages in the `childViewControllers` array.

Comment: This property is named [children](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621452-children) in Swift. Be careful to use this property and not the [viewControllers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller/1614106-viewcontrollers) property if you want access to all of the view controllers that the `UIPageViewController` has a reference to and not just the ones that are currently displayed by the `UIPageViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no access to the cached view controllers. You can maybe keep a pointer when you implement the Data Source methods to enable swiping:

```
– pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:
– pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in Kelin's answer, the children array contains the "loaded" view controllers. This information can also be used for propagating changes among loaded view controllers. (A common scenario would be ending the refresh of a refresh control.)

In Swift you can do something like this:

```
for vc in children {
    if let tableVC = vc as? UITableViewController {
         tableVC.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```

(Where **self** is of type **UIPageViewController**)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my consistency problem thanks to Kelin's answer. Every time I want to change the controllers in the `UIPageViewController` and make sure none of them are cached, I call this before the `setViewControllers` method:

```swift
for child in children {
    child.willMove(toParent: nil)
    child.view.removeFromSuperview()
    child.removeFromParent()
}
```